# How to correctly include dll's when publishing an ASP.net web site to run on mod_mono apache

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have published my ASP.net web site to my VPS which is currently running debian. I am running an apache web server with mod_mono to handle the ASP.net scripts.

The main page loads and runs as expected however the second page uses the MySQL Library from [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/1.0.html)
and I have included the bin folder which contains all of the binaries used within the project. However I am still receiving the following error

`The type or namespace name MySql could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

with the source for the error being on line 8.

```
Line 6: using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
Line 7: using System.Data;
Line 8: using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
```

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I see there are 2 types of dlls- for mono and for windows, did you include the dll for mono? id you try this dll on your dev environment?
submit your web.config file, it might help.